# AltBeacon library: distance estimate yields too low values

Tags: android, distance, ibeacon, triangulation

I'm trying to implement an Indoor Positioning System using iBeacon devices and trilateration algorithms (actually, multilateration). To do this, I use the AltBeacon library for Android, with which I can range all beacons near my device and get and estimate of the distance from each of them.

The problem is that I have been experiencing quite bad distance estimates, that prevent any possibility to calculate the position. In particular, distances are much lower than the actual values: when I'm standing 10+ meters away from a beacon, the library tells me I'm not farther than 3 meters.

I'm aware that iBeacons alone are not enough to achieve a high-precision IPS system, but I was at least expecting something comparable with the iPhone. Notice that I'm using a Nexus 5, which the library is calibrated on, according to the documentation. I'm also using an iPhone 5 for comparison, which seems to yield reasonable results, instead.

Any idea why this is happening? Do you have been able to use this library and get better results?

Comment: Do you use beacons with a battery? Because I had a similar problem because the batteries were to low

Comment: Yes, I use battery-powered beacons (more precisely, Kontakt.io beacons), but they all have more that 50% of remaining battery life. Notice that the RSSI values, which I guess have to do with battery, are the same as iPhone's. It's just that the library does not assign a reasonable distance estimate to those RSSIs.

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this are typically caused by bad transmitter power calibration values being sent by the beacon.

Understand that beacons transmit a one byte reference value indicating the expected signal strength at one meter.  It is critical that this value be correct for getting reasonable distance estimates.  If you dial up or dial down the transmitter power of the beacon (I'm not sure if Kontakt.io beacons support this, but many other vendors' beacons do) or if you install the beacon in any kind of enclosure, you need to re-calibrate and configure your beacon with this calibration value.

Because different mobile devices have different antennas, the standard device for doing a calibration is an iPhone 5.  To do so, you hold the iPhone 5 exactly one meter away from the beacon with its back facing the beacon, and use a free app like [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) to perform the calibration.  It will give you a reference value in dBm that needs to be configured into your beacon.  You can then use instructions from Kontakt.io to configure your beacon with this calibration value.

Comment: I am assuming the reference value at 1 meter is what the Locate app for Android displays as "Tx power". If that's it, then that value matches perfectly with what the iPhone measures as the rssi at 1 meter. So what else do I need to calibrate?

Comment: That is correct.  If you hold the Nexus 5 device one meter away, and go to the distance screen of the Locate app, what distance does it report?  If you then do a calibration at 1 meter with the Nexus 5, what calibration value does it report, and how does this compare with the Tx power field being transmitted?

Comment: The Nexus 5 displays a distance of 1 meter when I'm standing 1 meter away from the beacon. The RSSI also matches with the Tx Power. When I start moving away, however, the distance estimate increases very slowly, to the point that is shows 3 m when I'm actually 10 to 15 meters away.

Comment: The default algorithm can underestimate the distance for low-power transmitters.  Can you please tell me the RSSI you get at 1 meter and at 10 meters?

Comment: Sure. About -59 at 1 meter and -75 at 10 meters. The beacons are set to transmit at maximum power.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that the RSSI only drops off to -75 at 10 meters.  In similar tests, I usually see it drop of to around -85 at that distance.  Perhaps you are getting radio reflections in the area where you are testing that causes the signal to drop off less?  Another possibility is that the beacon transmitter is directional.  I'd be curious to hear if you get the same rssi results if you repeat the test outside away from obstructions, always keeping your phone aimed in the same orientation toward the same side of the beacon.